# How to Organize the data from a text file to a table?

Tags: file, text

i have a text file which is very vague .I want to arrange the data in a text file to table so that it is organized.

```
static void main(string[] args) {
     string fileName = @"C:\Users\Desktop\store.txt";

     using (System.IO.StreamReader sr = new System.IO.StreamReader(fileName))
     {
         String line;
         while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null) {
             Console.WriteLine(line);
         }
     }
}
```

By doing this .i can display the file.

**Output**

id:1 books id: 2 colleges id:3 professors

I want to organize this data in a table:

**Expected output:**

Id --------------   University

---

1 ----------------books

2 --------------  colleges

3------------    professors

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: fix your text file so it isn't "vague" and then show us an example of it.

Comment: i think you should post 4-5 different lines from the text file to see the actual data

Comment: the data is in json format

Answer (score 0):

Assuming id is unique as it should be, store the values in a map.  Id as key.  Unless by table, you mean visual representation.  You're going to have to read each strings (space-delimited), not by line.  Parse each strings.